# Broken hot shoe for Canon 5D Mk III

Tags: hotshoe-flash, hotshoe

I dropped my Canon 5D MkIII camera on the ground while it was attached to my speedlite transmitter (Godox X Pro). Luckily, the camera and lens was okay EXCEPT that the transmitter ripped the hot shoe off the camera. I have reattached the hot shoe but it’s no longer working properly.

After googling and testing I’ve concluded that the hot shoe is broken somehow but that the speedlites and triggers are all working properly. The hot shoe only works to trigger the light when a speedlite is directly attached to it (it fires when I hit the shutter) but the camera no longer recognizes the speedlite in the camera's menu settings.

I have triple checked that it’s not just about how secure the hot shoe connection is. In other words, I am confident that this has nothing to do with a loose hot shoe mount. I have tested this in various ways and tightened everything several times to make sure.

(And yes I have tested several times that the transmitters and speedlites to make sure they work properly.)

I think that this means that the trigger element* works (pin? Element? Not sure what to call it, there are several metal connectors on the hot shoe). But one of the OTHER metal elements is broken.

Which finally (sry for long message) leads me to my questions:

Which element on the hot shoe is the one that sends intelligent / specific info from the transmitter to the speedlite? Perhaps if I know which it is I can find a way to fix it?

Any thoughts, advice, knowledge, is supper helpful.

THANK YOU!

-Maggie

Comment: Where is the *test* button you are using? On the camera or on the transmitter? If on the transmitter it should work even when not attached to a camera.

Comment: Does the Speedlight that is directly attached work in TTL mode or only in Manual flash power mode? Can you still control the flash (i.e. set power level, first/second curtain sync, etc.) with the camera's internal menu when the flash is directly attached to the hot shoe?

Comment: Related: [Simple Explanation of the Hot Shoe Pins on Canon Cameras and Flashes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/106279/15871)

Comment: Thanks Michael - I just noticed that my camera isn't actually recognizing the attached speedlite when I check the menu settings, it fires when I hit the shutter but I can't set any of the settings in-camera. So whatever part of the camera that recognizes the specific instructions from the camera to the speedlite and back is broken. (And you are correct, the TEST button is arbitrary because it doesn't need to be connected to the camera to work)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fact your flash is also not working properly in your hotshoe.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search came up with two pin diagrams, which I have included below.

[image]

[image]

There is no individual pin or contact that is only for the transmitter. There are six connections that connect the hotshoe to the camera.  Because your flash is also not working normally, I would suspect that one or more of the connections was broken when the hot shoe was ripped off the camera.

This is not an easy repair or something you should attempt by yourself. Normally the entire top cover of the camera is replaced. Take your camera to a reputable camera repair shop for an estimate.

5D Mk III top cover
[image]

Comment: Thank you but I tested the trigger on my other camera and it works fine. Also, I have 2 identical triggers and the one that did not fall on the ground doesn't work on the camera that fell either (so it's definitely an issue on the camera).

Comment: I just noticed that my camera isn't actually recognizing the attached speedlite when I check the menu settings, it fires when I hit the shutter but I can't set any of the settings in-camera. So whatever part of the camera that recognizes the specific instructions from the camera to the speedlite and back is broken. I wish I knew more about it so I could fix it myself. Please let me know if you have any other thoughts on this. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited my answer since you now confirm the flash also does not work properly in the hotshoe.

Comment: Thank you Mike!